# Best way to set a big Amount of text to Textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, textview

I faced a new problem.
In my app, there is a part we called it X.
The X part have 5 tab ( using Viewpager and ...)
When user click on a button to start X activity, because, I must set text for all of the tabs (and there is 5 of them),there is a delay, based on the phone it's different, on low level phone its about, 4-7 second!!!
so, what can i do to solve the problem?
my way:
1- change my UI design and split the 5 tab into, 5 single activity.
2- use an progress bar( or something like progress bar) and don't change my design.( the problem is i don't know how to do this, i mean i don't know when all of the text are set)

what is the other solutions?
 So, if i want to use AsynckTask, the code would be like this right?
Main:

```
public class Law_main extends AppCompatActivity {
    FrameLayout fl_TEMP;
    TextView btn_ASD;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PagerAdapter adapter;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.law_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB 3"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB 4"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);


        fl_TEMP = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.TEMP);
        btn_ASD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ASD);


        new TxtTimer().execute();


        final View appbar = findViewById(R.id.appbar);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);



        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });


    }




    private class TxtTimer extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

this code act like this:
When user Click on to open X activity, user stay in the activity and then after a while, when all text got set, the x activity is open, so it's not helping at all.
Were am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you are retrieving your text, consider using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You can also put a progress circle on the fragment whilst it is loading so that the app doesn't appear to have frozen.

Comment: OK, it is a better way than change my UI. But there is a problem. i cant change the UI elements in the Doinbackground, and chge them in the other places like "onPreExecute" and ... not helping so much.

Comment: @mil You can change the UI in 'onPostExecute()', this method is run on the main thread.

Comment: OK rob, but i have a problem in my code, code u look at it? (added in the Main question)

Comment: @mil You need to create the tabs in the async tab 'doInBackground' method, this is where you put the main body of work which is slowing it down. What is the problem?

Comment: OK, so i think, the content of each tab create by this line, in the Adapter: 
adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
isn't it?

Comment: No, the tabs are created in your onCreate, creating a new PagerAdapter will instantiate the views needed. It's hard to tell as I can't see where the 'big text' is. Also what is the problem you referred to?

Comment: OK bro, tank you, everything is OK. The only problem was, the progress bar start after things get loaded, even if i start it in "onPreExecute", so i just use some static text.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what RobVoisey stated, and not knowing exactly your use case, I would load the first tab's text first to give the user something to look at and simultaneously load the text for the other tabs using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) whileshowing a loading graphic where appropriate and/or necessary.

Comment: You may think i'm crazy, but if my user immediately  after start activity, want to move to other tabs, thing may get laggy, so i just make user to stay until all of the text get load, and show user some kind of loading page, the result is, after loading user never experience any lag.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but feel it could be better to let the user navigate at will and if content is not loaded show them a loading graphic. That way the know the app is working, but still loading some info. That being said, of course, in some cases a loading screen may be more appropriate and only you can ultimately decide. Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

use fragments inside your tabs and load the content on demend using fragment lifecycle, youll have a starting point of 1/5 text being loaded on each fragment.

Comment: it;s not a best way, because in the low level device, we get a laggy  swapping for the first time.

Comment: didnt it ever crossed your mind that you were doing something wrong? like doing too much work on the UI thread rather than a worker thread? check yourself.

Comment: Your are right, but but the the program was a simple app, and i don't want  to load the text lines depend on the screen size, and another point, i just don't give down vote your answer, and Appreciate your answer.